# Why this method to remove an occurrence from an ArrayList don't work? (Java)

Tags: java, arraylist

How do I create a method that satisfies the following conditions?

```
/* 
 * removes all occurrences (if any) of x in the ArrayList object that the parameter list 
 * is referencing. If there is no occurrence of x then the content of the ArrayList
 * is not altered. 
 */
void removeOccurrences(ArrayList<Integer> list, int x)
```

NOTE: One may think on an algorithm such as the following:

```
    for (int i=0; i<list.size(); i++)
        if (list.get(i) == x)
          list.remove(i);
```

Comment: What is wrong with that implementation?

Comment: Won't a `ConcurrentModificationException` occur?

Comment: No, because there is no `Iterator` involved anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `.equals()` instead of `==`.  `==` checks whether two references point to the same object.  `.equals()` checks whether two objects represent the same *data*.

Comment: This is not an issue. Since one of the operands is a primitive, `x`, the other operand, an `Integer` value, will be unboxed.

Comment: Are you sure the `Integer` will be unboxed and not the `int` boxed?

Comment: [Yes.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.21.1)